# PowerShell ExchangeOnlineManagement - Add-MailboxFolderPermission: ObjectNotFoundException | Item wasn't found in the store

Tags: powershell, office365, ms-office, exchangewebservices, exchange-online

I am using the PowerShell command "Add-MailboxFolderPermission" of ExchangeOnlineManagement to share outlook calendars.
For some calendars it is just not working, I always get this exception:
[image]
The command is used like this:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "xxx" -User "xxx" -AccessRights Reviewer -SendNotificationToUser $true
```

For these calendars there is also a problem with sharing the calendar manually via outlook web:
[image]

Now the weird thing is, if I rename the calendar via outlook web it suddenly works (both in PowerShell and via web). Still works if I rename it back to the previous name.

Does anyone know, if this is a bug on Microsoft side and if I can solve this somehow for my PowerShell script?

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Are they new mailboxes ? it could be the folders haven't been provisioned yet one trick I've used in the past is use Test-MapiConnectivity -Identity "midwest\john" against the mailbox before you do any permission based operations. This ensure that the mailbox has had at least one full MAPI logon which will do any of the on-the-fly provisioning operations that maybe pending.

Comment: It is always the same mailbox but the calendars are new. We have one account which holds all calendars and they are shared to the users.
Unfortunately, the Test-MapiConnectivity command isn't working, I always get "Is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet". I guess that is due to missing permission.
Microsoft Docs say "The cmdlet logs on to the mailbox that you specify using the credentials of the account with which you're logged on to the local computer". And I don't have permission with my account. For the Add-Permission command I use Connect-ExchangeOnline in advance

Comment: In EWS Object not found is generally related to permissions so it maybe where your problem lies also. Not when you change permission on a Mailbox (even RBAC role) there can be a delay in these having an effect eg 15-60 replication convergence.

Comment: The mailbox permissions shouldn't be a problem as all the calendars remain in the same mailbox (the ones that work and the ones that don't) and I am using that exact mailbox-user that holds the calendars. So I should have access to the owned calendars, or is there a possibility to restrict the calendar itself?

Answer (score 0):

not sure, perhaps in your "identity" you have hardcoded the "Calendar" and because it's renamed then PS cannot find. To work with calendars I always check the name before.
I hope it helps

```
$calendarFolder = Get-ExoMailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $SmtpAddress -FolderScope Calendar | Where-Object { $_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar' }
$Identity     = "{0}:\{1}" -f $SmtpAddress, $calendarFolder.Name
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $Identity -User "xxx" -AccessRights Reviewer -SendNotificationToUser $true
```

Comment: Good thought but the identity is definitely correct, the Get-MailboxFolderPermission command with the exact same identity works